# Web.Forms project with Owin Startup works with IIS Express but not IIS when not debugging

Tags: asp.net, iis, owin, identityserver3

Some background: I've recently added a Startup.cs file to an older .NET 4.5.1 Web.Forms site in order to allow SSO authentication. I have another new project in the same solution which hosts the SSO code (IdentityServer3). I'd like to run both on local IIS (IIS 10) instead of IIS express so I can switch back and forth debugging the code.

Here's the code that calls out to the SSO process. It's in page_load for testing purposes.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var authProps = new AuthenticationProperties { };
    HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(authProps);
}
```

And the startup code for the client:

```
[assembly:OwinStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))]
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

        var authority = SSOSettings.SSOBaseUrl;
        var myUrl = "http://localhost/MyNamespace_WebApp/";

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "oidc",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            Authority = authority,
            ClientId = "myclientid",
            RedirectUri = myUrl,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = myUrl + "open/Login.aspx",
            ResponseType = "id_token token",
            Scope = "openid profile email",
            UseTokenLifetime = false
        });
    }
}
```

When the web project (the SSO client) is being debugged, either using IIS Express or when it is set as the startup project in Visual Studio and debugged using IIS, it will call out to the SSO site and start the SSO flow. But when I try to run it through IIS without debugging, I get an error:

> The string parameter 'namespaceName' cannot be null or empty.

The stack trace seems to indicate that something went wrong when trying to run the OWIN startup process.

```
[ArgumentException: The string parameter 'namespaceName' cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: namespaceName]
System.Web.UI.TagPrefixAttribute..ctor(String namespaceName, String tagPrefix) +3663848
System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule pModule, IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor, Byte** ppBlob, Byte* pEndBlob, Int32* pcNamedArgs) +0
System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule module, IRuntimeMethodInfo ctor, IntPtr& blob, IntPtr blobEnd, Int32& namedArgs) +48
System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) +846
System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType) +144
Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.SearchForStartupAttribute(String friendlyName, IList`1 errors, Boolean& conflict) +188
Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.GetDefaultConfiguration(String friendlyName, IList`1 errors) +68
Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.LoadImplementation(String startupName, IList`1 errorDetails) +89
Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.Load(String startupName, IList`1 errorDetails) +30
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.GetAppStartup() +165
(Stack trace truncated, but nothing in the stack trace that hits the site's custom code)
```

Is there maybe something on the OwinContext that is set differently when the site is debugging vs IIS?

Thanks!